# How to update a Global Variable after a function runs

Tags: javascript, html

```
window.onload = init;

function init(){
var gen = document.getElementById("generateButton");
gen.onclick = generate;}

var cnt = document.querySelectorAll(".box").length ;
var count = String(cnt);

function generate(){
for(j = 0; j < generatedNumber; j++){   
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.setAttribute("class", "box");
appendChild(div);
}
```

Hi, i'm new here. I think this is all the necessary code to convey my problem. What I need to do is update the cnt and count variables after the generate function has run through and created new div's with class box. I know I could use it as a local variable, but the assignment i'm doing asks for it to be global -.- .. i've been thinking it over for an hour and searching but have come up with nil. Thanks in advance.

p.s. it has to be pure javascript no jquery as I haven't gotten that far in my course.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking for help with.  `cnt` and `count` are global variables so you can assign to them at any time and they will retain their values.  At what point in time do you want to update them?

Comment: A global variable is ... global, and therefor accessible anywhere. Have you tried simply updating cnt after generate() runs?

Comment: well before I had the variables declared inside generate, I suppose updating them with the same values would technically fit the criteria; I just don't want my assignment handed back again :P

Answer (score 0):

Just update it at the end of the function...

```
var cnt = document.querySelectorAll(".box").length ;
var count = String(cnt);

function generate(){
  for(j = 0; j < generatedNumber; j++){   
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.setAttribute("class", "box");
    appendChild(div);
  }
  cnt = document.querySelectorAll(".box").length ;
  count = String(cnt);
}
```